# Paypal Java-SDK Payment Execute issue

Tags: java, spring, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate Papal with my Spring Web Service. I am refering [Advanced Server Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/) and using this [SDK Create Payment Sample](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/payments/servlet/PaymentWithPayPalServlet.java).

Here is my Client Side Code

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js">
</script>
<h1>Paypal Integration - Advanced Server Side Integration</h1>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script>
// Render the PayPal button

paypal.Button.render({

    // Set your environment

    env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

    // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

    payment: function() {

        // Make a call to the merchant server to set up the payment

        return paypal.request.post('http://localhost:8080/api/createpayment').then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            return res.payToken;
        });
    },

    // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

        // Make a call to the merchant server to execute the payment

        return paypal.request.post('http://localhost:8080/api/executepayment', {
            payToken: data.paymentID,
            payerId: data.payerID
        }).then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container').innerText = 'Payment Complete!';
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Here is my Web Service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/executepayment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody 
        Payment executePayment(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Payment createdPayment = null;
            try {

                final String clientID = "<clientId>";
                final String clientSecret = "<clientSecret>";
                // ### Api Context
                // Pass in a `ApiContext` object to authenticate
                // the call and to send a unique request id
                // (that ensures idempotency). The SDK generates
                // a request id if you do not pass one explicitly.
                APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(clientID, clientSecret, "sandbox");
                if (request.getParameter("payerId") != null) {
                    logger.info("Payment Execution");
                    Payment payment = new Payment();
                    if (request.getParameter("guid") != null) {
                        payment.setId(map.get(request.getParameter("guid")));
                    }

                    PaymentExecution paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
                    paymentExecution.setPayerId(request.getParameter("payerId"));


                    createdPayment = payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
                    logger.info("Executed Payment - Request :: \n " + Payment.getLastRequest());
                    logger.info("Exceuted Payment - Response :; \n " + Payment.getLastResponse());
                    //ResultPrinter.addResult(req, resp, "Executed The Payment", Payment.getLastRequest(), Payment.getLastResponse(), null);

                    //ResultPrinter.addResult(req, resp, "Executed The Payment", Payment.getLastRequest(), null, e.getMessage());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Execute Payment Exception ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return createdPayment;
        }
```

When I click on Paypal Checkout button. It popups the Paypal Login Screen and authorization is working fine. After that I am trying to execute payment using my API. But I am getting `500 Internal Server Error` when I call `payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecution)` method. Here is the complete Stacktrace

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-42] ERROR com.paypal.base.HttpConnection - Response code: 500   Error response: <html><head><title>JBoss Web/7.0.17.Final - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.paypal.foundation.security.ObjectEncryptionException.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/paypal/platform/ec/InternalError;Ljava/lang/Throwable;[Ljava/lang/String;)V    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:336)  org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)  org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)  com.paypal.api.utils.MultiReadServletFilter.doFilter(MultiReadServletFilter.java:23)    com.paypal.foundation.service.rest.logging.StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.doFilter(StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.java:95)    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)   com.paypal.common.resource.filter.SecurityContextFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextFilter.java:75)</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.paypal.foundation.security.ObjectEncryptionException.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/paypal/platform/ec/InternalError;Ljava/lang/Throwable;[Ljava/lang/String;)V org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101) org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)  org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)  org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)  com.paypal.api.utils.MultiReadServletFilter.doFilter(MultiReadServletFilter.java:23)    com.paypal.foundation.service.rest.logging.StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.doFilter(StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.java:95)    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)   com.paypal.common.resource.filter.SecurityContextFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextFilter.java:75)</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.paypal.foundation.security.ObjectEncryptionException.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/paypal/platform/ec/InternalError;Ljava/lang/Throwable;[Ljava/lang/String;)V  com.paypal.foundation.security.InvalidInputDataException.&lt;init&gt;(InvalidInputDataException.java:11)    com.paypal.foundation.security.crypto.AbstractIdEncryptor.decrypt(AbstractIdEncryptor.java:81)  com.paypal.domains.common.utils.crypto.impl.IdCryptUtilImpl.decryptId(IdCryptUtilImpl.java:103) com.paypal.domains.payment.dal.dao.impl.PaymentsFacadeDAOImpl.findPaymentByEncryptedId(PaymentsFacadeDAOImpl.java:301)  com.paypal.domains.payment.bo.impl.PaymentBOFactory.getPaymentForRoutingCheck(PaymentBOFactory.java:340)    com.paypal.api.service.impl.PaymentServiceImpl.checkRoutingToSymphony(PaymentServiceImpl.java:2167) com.paypal.api.service.impl.PaymentServiceImpl.executePayment(PaymentServiceImpl.java:811)  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor168.invoke(Unknown Source)   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)  org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101) org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)  org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)  org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerReque2017-05-03 17:48:33 ERROR UserController:740 - Create Payment Exception 
stFilter.java:76)   com.paypal.api.utils.MultiReadServletFilter.doFilter(MultiReadServletFilter.java:23)    com.paypal.foundation.service.rest.logging.StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.doFilter(StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.java:95)    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)   com.paypal.common.resource.filter.SecurityContextFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextFilter.java:75)</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.17.Final logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/7.0.17.Final</h3></body></html>
response-code: 500  details: null
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException.createFromHttpErrorException(PayPalRESTException.java:72)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:431)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:295)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:228)
    at com.paypal.api.payments.Payment.execute(Payment.java:226)
    at com.statementgames.controllers.UserController.createPayment(UserController.java:640)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.statementgames.filters.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.paypal.base.exception.HttpErrorException: Response code: 500 Error response: <html><head><title>JBoss Web/7.0.17.Final - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.paypal.foundation.security.ObjectEncryptionException.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/paypal/platform/ec/InternalError;Ljava/lang/Throwable;[Ljava/lang/String;)V    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:336)  org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)  org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)  com.paypal.api.utils.MultiReadServletFilter.doFilter(MultiReadServletFilter.java:23)    com.paypal.foundation.service.rest.logging.StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.doFilter(StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.java:95)    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)   com.paypal.common.resource.filter.SecurityContextFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextFilter.java:75)</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.paypal.foundation.security.ObjectEncryptionException.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/paypal/platform/ec/InternalError;Ljava/lang/Throwable;[Ljava/lang/String;)V org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101) org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)  org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)  org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)  com.paypal.api.utils.MultiReadServletFilter.doFilter(MultiReadServletFilter.java:23)    com.paypal.foundation.service.rest.logging.StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.doFilter(StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.java:95)    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)   com.paypal.common.resource.filter.SecurityContextFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextFilter.java:75)</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.paypal.foundation.security.ObjectEncryptionException.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/paypal/platform/ec/InternalError;Ljava/lang/Throwable;[Ljava/lang/String;)V  com.paypal.foundation.security.InvalidInputDataException.&lt;init&gt;(InvalidInputDataException.java:11)    com.paypal.foundation.security.crypto.AbstractIdEncryptor.decrypt(AbstractIdEncryptor.java:81)  com.paypal.domains.common.utils.crypto.impl.IdCryptUtilImpl.decryptId(IdCryptUtilImpl.java:103) com.paypal.domains.payment.dal.dao.impl.PaymentsFacadeDAOImpl.findPaymentByEncryptedId(PaymentsFacadeDAOImpl.java:301)  com.paypal.domains.payment.bo.impl.PaymentBOFactory.getPaymentForRoutingCheck(PaymentBOFactory.java:340)    com.paypal.api.service.impl.PaymentServiceImpl.checkRoutingToSymphony(PaymentServiceImpl.java:2167) com.paypal.api.service.impl.PaymentServiceImpl.executePayment(PaymentServiceImpl.java:811)  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor168.invoke(Unknown Source)   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)  org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101) org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)  org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)  org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)  com.paypal.api.utils.MultiReadServletFilter.doFilter(MultiReadServletFilter.java:23)    com.paypal.foundation.service.rest.logging.StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.doFilter(StandardOuterTransactionCALFilter.java:95)    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)   com.paypal.common.resource.filter.SecurityContextFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextFilter.java:75)</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.17.Final logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/7.0.17.Final</h3></body></html>
    at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:162)
    at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:65)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:417)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/706473799bd24b5792e463df41140a61/execute
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:132)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/706473799bd24b5792e463df41140a61/execute
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:117)
    ... 47 more
```

I can't figure out whats going wrong. Is there any issue in Paypal-Java-SDK or in my Server side code. Am I doing anything Wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because of wrong Payment Id. I just changed the code as

```
if (request.getParameter("paymentId") != null) {
    payment.setId(request.getParameter("paymentId"));
}
```

I think Paypal should handle this kind of errors and show some proper error message in Response JSON like Payment ID missing, Invalid Payment ID or something. It's weird to get 500 Internal Server Error and It's very hard to debug.